# What if nid reaches the maximum ?

Tags: 7, nodes, database

What if my `nid` reaches the maximum allowed value of [MySql int type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

I have made a drupal.org site search that ends up [Here](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_search/auto%20increment%20reaches%20maximum). And also i found [Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). In an app that i am about to build is a contact manager for students. Which is supposed to pull gmail, fb contacts in future. My plan is to make each contact a node. Is it a good idea to keep each contact as separate node? Can you suggest any other brilliant mechanism to handle this?

I am worried about the overflow of `nid` as i made a test run using may own gmail id, which ends up in a 1025 new nodes.

I am using typical Drupal 7.14 installation.

Comment: I checked to see that `nid` in `node` table is of type `int(10)`. That means we can have `10!` number of nodes. I don't think that your requirement might extend that value...

Comment: @indrock `10! number of nodes` means ? 10K ?

Comment: refer [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/factorial.html). I'm not that good at math but I think there should at least be `10!` (or may be `10*10!`) different numbers.

Comment: According to my Mac's calculator `10! = 3,628,800`

Comment: @Clive, does my question make any sense? or its foolish?. Anyway what if a 1000 users provided with a screen like this? http://drupal.org/files/images/Screen%20shot%202010-09-09%20at%2010.15.44%20AM.png

Comment: @indrock, suppose i have covered `10!` whats then ?

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid question...a site with 4 million nodes doesn't sound beyond the realms of possibility. Plus, you can't just change the int length to, say, `11` in the node table, as many other tables relate the `nid` and will still have a max int length of `10`. I'm interested to see how this one pans out

Comment: @NikhilMohan then I suppose I would change the value of `nid` to hold more values by the query `ALTER TABLE  'node' CHANGE  'nid'  'nid' INT( 15 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT  'The primary identifier for a node.'`

It would increase your number of values to `(15 !) - (10 !) = 1 307 670 739 200`

Comment: @indrock, have you seen Cliv's comment? I agree with him +1. you can't just change the int length to, say, 11 in the node table, as many other tables relate the nid

Comment: @Clive : I found the answer to this. Actually I was wrong considering the length of the integer as the capacity which would be stored in the column. `int(10)` means it will display width of the integers. there is an interesting [article there](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html). So, even changing the value will  not affect the existing site (i checked on my installation to confirm).

Comment: @NikhilMohan : look for my comment above :-)
Actually for normal `int` type, you'll have values from 0 to 2^32 − 1 or 4294967295 that is something above 4 billion. I'm doubtful that your database would go beyond that.

Comment: @indrock Thanks I'll have a read through that, sounds interesting

Comment: See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) : max unsigned int is 4,294,967,295. No need for complicated maths : just RTFM :D.

Answer (score 6):

If nid reaches the maximum your site will no longer be able to create new nodes as there will be SQL errors whenever Drupal tries to insert a new nid.

Chances are though, that drupal.org will hit this limit before you do, regardless of what you're doing to your site in any useful real-world application.

If drupal.org gets anywhere close to 4 billion nodes, there definitely will be a workaround readily available for you.

Comment: Upvote for creativity in the answer.

Comment: @NikhilM would you consider marking my answer as correct?