# What's the limit of drupal?

Tags: performance

I want to know what's the limit of drupal?:

1. Maximum number of nodes .
2. Maximum number of content type .
3. Maximum of files 's size .

And That without interruption of service . 
I am using Apache + mysql +redhat  .
Thank you very much

Comment: 1. Defined by your MySQL instance (depends on [max integer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/what-if-nid-reaches-the-maximum)). 2. Ditto. 3. Defined by your apache/php settings. Whether or not your site is _happy and responsive_ with extreme numbers of nodes is down to your server infrastructure and very little else. Basically as @Bart said, there's no real answer to this question

Comment: I had a same question with some great info check it http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/what-if-nid-reaches-the-maximum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've worked with sites that:
 - have millions of nodes.
 - hundreds of thousands of files.
 - sites that deal with video (gb sized files).

In the above cases it's something that drupal is built on top of and not drupal it's self that can be an issue. Million of nodes; use a database that can handle a lot of I/O ([read this blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/)). Hundreds of thousands of files; setup your directory structure so you have less than [5,000 files](https://serverfault.com/questions/129953/maximum-number-of-files-in-one-ext3-directory-while-still-getting-acceptable-per) in a dir. Large file sizes; there are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864570/very-large-uploads-with-php), this is a PHP limit [not a drupal one](http://groups.drupal.org/node/20291).

Answer (score 6):

That depends on a lot of factors: hardware, configuration of your LAMP stack, ...

The only real way to test this is to benchmark it yourself, on your hardware, under your circumstances.

There's no real answer to this question.

Comment: I have a mysql server 5.1 and php5.4 and redhat server with 4Go of ram and apache2

Comment: As I said, even if you'd give every detail of your setup, we'd still be guessing. The only real way to test this is to benchmark it. To be honest, I wouldn't worry to much about the limits of Drupal. If you get close to reaching the limits of Drupal, there will be ways to work around that. For example you could use MongoDB instead of MySQL for storing fields, logs, ...

Answer (score 1):

There are limits set both within Drupal's configuration and by the limitations of your server. For example, the PHP memory limit is set by the admin, and determines how much system memory Drupal can use up. The hard drive space of your system determines how many gigs of code, database contents, and files can be stored. There are many such limitations, some of them available for change as settings, and some inherent in the limitations of your hardware and software setup itself.

Because the performance-determining variables and their potential combinations are so numerous, it's more practical to do some in-situ benchmark testing with your particular site on your particular stack on your particular hardware using your particular internet connection than it is to try to predict the performance from some kind of calculation of every possible variable.

Even then, your metrics may be very different in a dev environment with just a few users making requests than they would be in production use, where traffic to your site could be dramatically more voluminous.

Comment: Thank you very much,I asked that question because i'm conception a new system when it's possible to make 2000 nodes per hour, so im wondering if drupal will do it or i have to develop my own system

Comment: It depends on what the nodes contain and how they're generated, as well as your storage space and your PHP memory limit. There's no way to answer your question without testing your machine.

Comment: 2000 nodes per hour is not that large ;)

Comment: @AyeshK Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: sorry i was saying, adding 2000 nodes per hour will not make the site perform worse in most normal sites -- not related to practical php and mysql. I have had a site that crawls ~12000 nodes per hour and still it works for normal users.